Export Tab > Device has a orange BG in blender

setting it to CPU makes it Orange and setting it to GPU makes it Yellow 
it doesn't happen in Other Projects, only this specific one 
i was messing around with some export settings which i dont really remember and Setting Device to CPU still uses GPU for exporting 
how can i make it normal?

It looks as if you've managed to keyframe the setting. Right-click on it and choose "Delete Keyframe".

I didn't even know you could keyframe that

@aidan-j-rhoden Nor did I until I tried it and to be honest I can't see the point. I presume it's just available to every setting by default.

@JohnEason Although there are definitely settings in Blender which cannot be keyframed even if you tried...

@GordonBrinkmann Is that a challenge to go through every one and make a list? If so I'll defer to your knowledge and give that a miss thanks! :^))

@JohnEason Haha, no it was just more thinking aloud like, if by default they make every setting keyframeable, and they manually take out some of them and they forgot this one or the other way round, none can be keyframed except for those which get this option and they accidentally enabled it here...

I have managed to keyframe the setting Device Setting. a simple Right-click on it and "Delete Keyframe" was the solution
